# Fancybox gallery

Tags: media, javascript

I have one button in node body called 'Gallery' and I need to show fancybox with thumbnails when button is clicked.

What is the simplest way to do that?

Comment: Have you looked at the fancboxy module? 

https://drupal.org/project/fancybox

Comment: yes, I already install module, problem is how to use it like I describe above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create gallery using [Views](https://drupal.org/project/Views). I create block and insert that block in node's body using [Insert Block](https://drupal.org/project/insert_block) module.

My first image in gallery is button because I need to show full gallery only when button is clicked, I use [this solution](https://drupal.org/node/1933864#comment-7138128) to hide other images (but to view that images in fancyBox)...